# Run through a variety of ranges in a list algorithmically

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out the best way to check a variety of ranges of a list algorithmically and drawing a blank. Here is what the ranges it should check should look like.

```
#first it checks the whole list, then
foo[1:]
foo[:-1]
foo[2:]
foo[1:-1]
foo[:-2]
foo[3:]
foo[2:-1]
foo[1:-2]
foo[:-3]
#etc, for as long as the ranges will fit in the list
```

The first and last steps are easy enough - essentially I could just use

```
foo[iter:]
foo[:-iter]
```

But the intermediate ones are where I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: what you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to match pieces of a list to criteria. If I have a list  ['1', '2', '3', '4'] I want it to check 1 2 3 4 > 2 3 4 > 1 2 3 > 3 4 > 2 3 > 1 2 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1 against a list of possible answers. So if '1 2 3 4' and '1' are both possible answers, it should choose '1 2 3 4' first.

Answer (score 2):

```
map(lambda x: foo[x[0]:-x[1]], itertools.permutations(range(1, 4), 2))
```

Comment: This will generate all the intermediate slices.  For example, [(1, -2), (1, -3), (2, -1), (2, -3), (3, -1), (3, -2)] here.

Comment: Is this tailored to a specific length of list? I'm not familiar with permutations, but I'm assuming the '4' is the restricting factor if there is one.

Comment: The '4' is only to check the permutations listed in my comment.  If you need more permutations, just increase from 4 to higher numbers.  If the length of foo is too short, you'll get an empty list from the map

Comment: Cool. I'll have to look up how to actually *use* map, haha. But thank you. :)

Comment: It's basically doing the same as the other answer.  Just in 1 line instead of 2 nested for loops.

Comment: It's not quite, because in order to have an open-ended slice you need to use `None` and those permutations include only integers.

Comment: I just don't understand how to plug it into the rest of my code. The other answer, I understand foo[start:start+length] is my desired output, but for yours, I don't yet know how to access what it's actually creating.

Answer (score 1):

This works, although at first glance it is slightly inelegant due to the magic-number ranges.

```
def decreasing_ranges(seq):
    for length in range(len(seq), 0, -1):
        for start in range(len(seq) - length, -1, -1):
            yield foo[start:start + length]
```

Comment: It's far more elegant than what I had! Thanks :)